# How much does Shalltear love Ainz? (All quotes from the source material)

Tags: overlord

I just finished season 1 and started the still ongoing season 2 from the anime and I loved Shalltear's character.

Now I wonder, were there any quotes in the light novel where it is shown Shalltear loves Ainz? Either through verbal or physical acts? Like blushing when Ainz's nearby, or fighting Albedo to marry him... I take it that the light novels might include more moments like these than the anime.

It seems that what I've watched so far covers volumes 1-4, so I am mainly looking for occurrences from those 4 volumes. Any other suggestions are still welcome as long as they don't include spoilers. Namely, all quotes are accepted if they don't spoil the story.

Comment: _How do I love thee? Let me count the ways._ Elizabeth Browning (Well, someone had to say it!)

Comment: I updated your question to use a less broad phrasing and a bit more to the point. If you feel I edited out crucial information, feel free to add it back in.

Comment: Thanks for the edit XD I will keep things more to the the point as you suggest and edit it again. I hope this time I've made it clear for everyone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Revision` - I had already finished writing the documents a while back, but I now thought that giving a general overview would be good. Once you click on either the word [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6XCWndr5) or [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RkUhqncZhr6SMu8mKPKQ4REro45-poUAAPso9KaUH-U/view) you’ll be redirected to the main page, which contains very relevant instructions, so please read it first. This will lead to a complete understanding of the heart of my answer to your question: Quotes from Drama CDs, Quotes from Side Stories, Quotes from light novels (volumes 1-4), Quotes from light novels (volume 11). After that, there are the final conclusions on Shalltear’s love for Ainz.

As a side note, I recently answered another question in this forum about Overlord’s translation, so I decided to also edit these files so that they include the comparison between the official translation and the fan translation in more detail.

---

If you just wait for a few days, I'll give you many pages worth of such sentences as well as a full analysis on Shalltear's love for Ainz. I'm linking my own [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6XCWndr5) and [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RkUhqncZhr6SMu8mKPKQ4REro45-poUAAPso9KaUH-U/view) for that purpose. (Right now they're visibly empty, but it will take me very few days to gather enough material to create a very long document)

In the meantime, I will explain one of quotes from Bhavin as it's quite revealing. I'll also quote a conversation between Shalltear and a death knight from the side story "Emissary of the king" that the author wrote.

> この二人の対立は恋敵であることに起因している。
>   アインズはアルべドとシャルティア、両者から惚れられていた。絶世の美女二人に愛される。これ を喜ばない男はいないだろう。

This sentence that Bhavin mentioned (from volume 2 of the light novels) is very beautiful.

```
この = These
二人 = two people
の = possessive marker
対立 = opposition
は = subject marker
恋敵 = rivals in love
であること = the fact that
に = from
起因している = originates
```

All together...

These two's opposition originates from the fact that they are rivals in love.

```
アインズ = Ainz
は = subject marker
アルべド = albedo
と = and
シャルティア = shalltear
両者 = both
から = from/by
惚れられていた = to be in love with
```

All together,

About Ainz, to be loved by both Albedo and Shalltear

```
絶世の美女 = peerless beauty
二人 = 2 people
に = from
愛される = loved
これ = this
を = grammar marker
喜ばない = not be happy
男 = man
は = subject marker
いない = doesn’t exist
だろう = most likely
```

All together,

Loved by two peerless beauties, to not be happy of this, most likely there doesn't exist a man.

The reason the sentence is so beautiful is because the author used a different kind of love each time, showing how complete Albedo and Shalltear's love for Ainz is.

恋敵 (*koigataki*) = it uses *koi*, which can only mean romantic love. They fell in love with Ainz in a romantic way, the way you would feel for your boyfriend /girlfriend. It is always 100% romantic.

惚れる (*horeru*) = to be in love with/to be infatuated with or consumed by (romantic.) The romantic feeling is very strong on all occasions. The usual translation would be to "fall in love with" but context should be taken into consideration. The next love word used makes it clear it means “to fall in love with” with a very strong feeling of infatuation as well.

愛される (*aisareru*) which means a very deep type of love (to be loved by.) The word "愛" is the standard word for love in Japanese. However, Japanese VERY rarely say this word, and some people go their whole life without saying it. So it has come to have quite a deep meaning, you will almost always see *suki* used in the place of *ai*. Unlike the other 2, this type of love doesn't necessarily have to be just romantic when referring to another person, though it's even rarer to use it for family or a friend.

So far, Albedo and Shalltear are the only floor masters that have shown the first 2 kinds of love. The third type of love should also include romantic love in their case.

---

Regarding the conversation I said I was going to quote, it is from the side story "Emissary of the King" that Maruyama wrote. Ainz sends one of his servants, a death knight, to ask the floor masters what it is they really desire. Shalltear is a bit skeptical at first.

> "Then… Is the reason you came to me first because I am the furthest away from Ainz-sama? Was it purely a matter of distance?"
>
> It wasn't like that. The Death Knight told her what his master had said, that "Shalltear is a very important person." The mood changed in an instant.   Something that felt like hot air roiled in front of him. There was no change in Shalltear — no. Her crimson pupils glowed like lava.
>
> "—Forgive me. I must have gone deaf for a moment, so I didn't hear what you said just now. Do forgive me. Could you please tell me  what Ainz-sama said, one more time?"
>
> It was hard to believe that undead, with their immunity to biological status effects, could go deaf. But he had no reason to deny Shalltear's request. So, he repeated himself.
>
> The corner of Shalltear's mouth turned up. "—Ha! Hahaha! Ahhh, if only Albedo was here to listen to this! Hahaha!" After having a good
>   laugh, Shalltear continued asking the Death Knight  other questions.
>
> "Did Ainz-sama say anything about Albedo?" After hearing that Ainz hadn't mentioned anything, Shalltear was all smiles. ...  Conversations were like passing in basketball. If the exchange ended after only a couple of rounds, something was wrong. … Seeing Shalltear's discomfort, the Death Knight asked the final question, "What do you want?"
>
> Shalltear's smile was bewitchingly beautiful as she made her reply. "I want Ainz-sama's love. I don’t mean to say it only has to be me. After all, it's normal for a great man to claim many women for himself. It would be surprising if any woman could resist an absolutely amazing man like Ainz-sama. However, I want to be the first in his heart."

(Later, Ainz-sama’s servant goes back to Ainz and tells him what happened and what she desires.)

> "Very well. Then let me hear the answer to the last question."   As he heard Shalltear's answer, Ainz sagged like a puppet whose strings had been cut. "... Besides Ainz. Append that to the last question the next time you ask it. Understood?"

(Later, the death knight servant goes to Cocytus and asks)

> "What do you want… besides Ainz-sama." Cocytus seemed to grin at the addition. "…I. See. Someone. Asked. For. That. It. Must. Have been. Albedo. Or. Shalltear."

(Each servant wants a different thing: Aura wants magical beasts, Mare wants plants… On the other hand, Albedo and Shalltear love Ainz too much, and they may never get their wish granted.)

Comment: Wow Dude Thanks!!! Your answer already seems long and amazing to me. Can't wait to see the full document in your links :)

Comment: This is an epic answer! I wish I could give multiple upvotes!

Answer (score 5):

Together with Albedo, Shalltear madly fell in love with Ainz. In the Overlord world, there is a great number of quotes where it is shown Shalltear loves Ainz, so making a complete list would be a very difficult task to deal with. But I can quickly search for 3 quotes from the volumes you asked for, one for each volume, to comply with your request in a reasonable way.

Official translation made by Yen press. Author: Kugane Maruyama. Official translator of the Overlord series: Emily Balistrieri. Quote from volume 2, just before the first part of “two adventurers” starts.

**“The reason for their conflict was that they were rivals in love. Both Albedo and Shalltear had fallen for Ainz—i.e., he was loved by two incomparable beauties. What guy wouldn’t be happy about that?”**

Shalltear and Albedo want to become Ainz’s wife, spending the rest of their lives in a romantic relationship with him. I’ll skip their insults to one another and just point out their final agreement.

Official translation, volume 1. Intermission before chapter 3 starts.

**“The fight…is over. Now they’re just—”
“The issue is simply who will be his first wife.”
“We concluded that it would be bizarre for the absolute ruler of the Great Tomb of Nazarick to have only one queen. But now we have to decide who his primary will—”**

They start rallying allies from Nazarick that will support their love for him. No other servant wants to marry him, but some of them take sides, supporting either Albedo or Shalltear’s love for Ainz.

Official translation, volume 3, chapter 1, just before part 4 starts. Shalltear says this.

**“Yes, I will do a splendid job carrying out the duties Lord Ainz bestowed upon me, and my praises he will sing: ‘Nice job. You’re my most precious slave.’ And then he’ll say, ‘You are the one most fit to stand at my side.’”**

In general, Shalltear likes to daydream that, one day, he’ll choose her, and then they will get married, spend the rest of their lives together and become a happy family with their sons and daughters. She doesn’t want to marry anyone who’s not Ainz, she’ll wait her whole life to become his wife and she’s very loyal to him.

[image]

Comment: Lol, that last picture. After getting resurrected, she realizes she's nude and is near Ainz and she inquires if their first time will be in the throne room. It was pretty funny considering the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Shalltear loves Momonga and would easily give her life for him no matter what the situation is. But what's really interesting is that she would put anything at risk to build a romantic relationship between her and Ainz. Albedo and Shalltear are his most devoted servants, and this is shown in situations where servants are asked what they would be able to give to be close to Ainz etcetera. All servants would like to hang around with Momonga, but no one can beat those 2. If need be, they will sink to an incredibly low level because, as stated in the series when talking about them, women in love will do anything. Shalltear loving Ainz does not have to entail reciprocal love, but let's hope Momonga becomes at least a little more bold in the volumes to come.